# how to convert int to uint

Tags: c#

I have `int` variable with value `820924`
when I'm trying to convert it like that:

`(uint)data[structure["MICROSECONDS"].Index]`

it doesn't work.

This doesn't work as well

`unchecked((uint)data[structure["MICROSECONDS"].Index])`

I receive `Specified cast is not valid.` exception.

Data stores `object`, but at run time I should try to convert to `int`. I'm almost sure. I've printed object value it was `820924`, however I don't know how to print object type, but it must be int.

Code:

```
object value = data[structure["MICROSECONDS"].Index];
Console.WriteLine("xx MICROSECONDS type " + value.GetType());
Console.WriteLine("xx casting " + value);
Console.WriteLine("xx cast ok" + (uint)value);
```

Result:

```
xx MICROSECONDS type System.Int32
xx casting 820924
```

Comment: `var i = (uint)820924;` works. Is it possible that your `Index` returns a string?

Comment: @L.B it shouldn't be so but I don't know how to check this at runtime

Comment: no i don't have debugger on remote machine, but I can launch debug build

Comment: “however i don't know how to print object type” – `myObject.GetType()`

Comment: it was printed that object type is Int32

Comment: i print message. the message is "Specified cast is not valid." and that's all

Answer (score 64, accepted):

First of all you should check the type of your value. You can do it by calling `obj.GetType()` method (either in your code directly or in Immediate window).

If it is `int` then you can do:

```
uint u = (uint) (int) obj;
```

Please note that it differs from your cast because it **casts** to `int` and then **converts** to `uint` while you were trying to **cast** to `uint`. `int` cannot be cast to `uint` and that is why you get the `InvalidCastException`. `int` can be only **converted** to `uint`. It is confusing that both **conversion** and **cast** operators look same in code: `u = (uint) x`.

Easier thing you can do is calling a specific method from `Convert` class:

```
uint u = Convert.ToUInt32(x);
```

Comment: A simpler way of checking the type of an object starting with C# 7.0 is using the "is" keyword:

if (myObject is int)...

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that `int` is stored as `object`. `Int` derives from object but `uint` doesn't derive from `int` so you can't cast `int` stored as `object` to `uint`. First you have to cast it to `int` and then to `uint` because that cast is valid. Try it yourself:

```
object o = 5;//this is constant that represents int, constant for uint would be 5u
uint i = (uint)o;//throws exception
```

But this works:

```
object o = 5;
int i = (int)o;
uint j = (uint)i;
```

or

```
object o = 5;
uint i = (uint)(int)o; //No matter how this looks awkward
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the `Index` property is returning a String or something.  You could do the following:

```
var num = Convert.ToUInt32(data[structure["MICROSECONDS"].Index]);
```

`Convert.ToUInt32` is overloaded with all the relevant types that a `uint` can be converted from.

Answer (score 1):

If Index is a string, or has a numeric like representation when converted to a string you can try:

```
UInt32 microSecondsIndex;
if(Uint32.TryParse(data[structure["MICROSECONDS"].Index.ToString()],out microSecondsIndex))
{
   //Do Stuff
}
else
{
    //Do error handling
}
```

Comment: @Snowbear It could be a string, have seen weirder data storage, but noted, have edited to reflect the constraint on TryParse

Comment: I mean it is obviously not a string because if it would be a string (at compile time) then converting it to `uint` won't even compile. But question states that it can be compiled, which means that it is an `object`. And `object` cannot be passed to `TryParse` directly