# Getting Nested Hierarchy returns invalid status code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, vsix

Basically I am trying to get the nested hierarchy of a folder in a project. Down below you can see a simplified version of my code, where I take the first node of the Hierarchy which is a folder.

```cs
CurrentHierarchy.GetProperty(VSConstants.VSITEMID_ROOT, (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_FirstVisibleChild, out var tempNode);

if (IsFolder)
{
    var guid = typeof(IVsHierarchy).GUID;

    var result = CurrentHierarchy.GetNestedHierarchy((uint)(int)tempNode, ref guid, out var hierarchyObjectPointer, out var nested); // Returns invalid status code

    var hierarchy = (IVsHierarchy)Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(hierarchyObjectPointer);
    Marshal.Release(hierarchyObjectPointer);
}
```

Anyhow the variable `result` contains the value `-2147483648` or `int.MinValue`, which is of course not valid. I wonder what I am doing wrong here. I looked at a couple of web pages: [GitHub 1](https://github.com/EWSoftware/VSSpellChecker/blob/6d1b6f6c1de35ebef1e0a2c727e4a8b36aed0b6e/Source/VSSpellChecker/ProjectSpellCheck/SpellCheckFileInfo.cs#L469), [GitHub 2](https://github.com/Particular/ServiceMatrix/blob/9e963c35538cceb1a40d7ea4084f9959cd4b506e/src/ServiceMatrix.Automation/Commands/CollapseFoldersCommand.cs#L37) and [Hot Examples](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/IVsHierarchy/GetNestedHierarchy/php-ivshierarchy-getnestedhierarchy-method-examples.html), but they seem to be the same what I am doing.

Note that the `CurrentHierarchy` represents the projects hierarchy and `IsFolder`'s value is actually correct e.g. The node is actually a folder.

---

### Edit

After digging some more around I noticed that `GetNestedHierarchy` is actually returning `VSConstants.E_FAIL` which means:

> If the requested interface is not supported on the hierarchy object, Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSConstants.E_NOINTERFACE is returned. The caller would then treat this node as if it had no children, if the requested interface had been essential (as is often the case when the requested interface is IID_IVsUIHierarchy).

Which even confuses me more, because it the node I am passing to the method is indeed a folder.

---

### Edit 2

It seems like the code works fine, if the `IVsHierarchy` represents an `IVsSolution`, but as soon as I try to get the nested hierarchy of a nested hierarchy, it won't work anymore.

Comment: Is it necessary to cast (uint)(int)tempNode as shown? Why not just cast to (uint)?

Comment: @Jazimov Yes it is, you can't cast an `int` which is boxed in an `object` directly to an `uint`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13290603/how-to-convert-int-to-uint) for more information.

Comment: I didn't realize TempNode is an object. Furthermore, be careful. For example, (uint)3000000000 returns 3000000000 but (uint)(int)3000000000 throws an error. Why not use Convert.ToUInt32(tempNode) instead to unbox?

Comment: @Jazimov yeah, that would probaply be a better option, thanks for that one. Sadly this won't fix the error.

Comment: Sure. At least we know that it's not a casting issue. I looked deeper and saw this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/misc/using-libraries-from-partially-trusted-code?redirectedfrom=MSDN. The E.NOINTERFACE error could be related to a security/trust issue across the application/library boundary. Might that be the root cause?

Comment: @Jazimov actually `GetNestedHierarchy` returns `VSConstants.E_FAIL`  and nothing else.

Comment: Doh--you did say that. But when I looked that up I see: "Full trust for the immediate caller. This member cannot be used by partially trusted code. For more information, see Using Libraries from Partially Trusted Code." Might there be a trust issue?

Comment: @Jazimov Good idea, I will try with a strong name. Although it would still confuse me since all the other COM calls work perfectly fine. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @Jazimov actually strong naming didn't help. So I think this shouldn't be a trust issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This whole thing is actually a lot easier than first expected. I actually miss understood the the use of `GetNestedHierarchy` and the whole principle overall. So let me explain for everyone else.

At first glance you might think that a folder and any node that is expandable is a Hierarchy, but no!

What is a Hierarchy even then? Actually from my tests a hierarchy is only a **Solution** and a **Project** and **nothing** else. So if you want to get an item in a folder of project you'll need to get each child by calling `GetProperty` over and over.

```cs
hierarchy.GetProperty(folderItemId, (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_FirstChild, out var folderItem);
hierarchy.GetProperty(folderItem, (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_FirstChild, out var folderItemItem);
```

Basically the project `IVsHierarchy` hosts **all** the items in the project.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have an answer for you among these points:

Set a breakpoint here:

`var result = CurrentHierarchy.GetNestedHierarchy((uint)(int)tempNode, ref guid, out var hierarchyObjectPointer, out var nested); // Returns invalid status code`

Then:

1. Inspect the CurrentHierarchy object to make sure that it has a FirstChild property value that's not null. If it's null you will get a return value of `VSConstants.E_FAIL`.
2. Inspect the entire hierarchy for a node that has an ID value equal to the uint tempNode value you passed in. If no node ID matches the tempNode value then get a return value of `VSConstants.E_FAIL`.

Does the above help?

Comment: Actually I tested this already, but I can get tall properties e.g. `Save Name` and more from it, with the exact same hierarchy and ID.

Comment: I actually miss understood the purpose of `GetNestedHierarchy`, if you are curious take a look at my answer. Thanks for you help anyway!

Comment: I went into the source code for GetNestedHierarchy() in order to help you. The above information is correct. So you could give a up-vote for my efforts even if you don't feel it was the answer...

Comment: Yea you are correct, I should have done that, and I'll, but begging for an up-vote isn't really what I consider to be good either.

Comment: @Twenty: There's a protocol here, I wasn't "begging"--I was saying what you could do because I had spent about an hour on your issue (seems no one else was as motivated to try to help you)--I know what I posted is factually correct because it's tied to source code. I had little to go on because you posted a small code snippet with no values to troubleshoot. The incentive people have on the Stack Exchange Network to help for free is only to receive points for their efforts. Everyone needs to play fair for sites like this to thrive. Thank you for your points and good luck with your programming.

Comment: I didn't mean to offend you or anything and yes I should have got you an up-vote in the first place, but just in my opinion I would write such a comment to a more inexperienced person. Anyhow I was a bit to harsh though, so I am sorry, anyhow I really appreciated your help.